# Reference for Uniformization Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I would appreciate if someone could point me to some introductory literature/resources where I can learn about **Poincare's Uniformization Theorem** at a basic level.

Any good powerpoint notes, short papers or video lectures would be nice. I want to learn about the result in general, the proof, how it relates to other important theorem's in geometry and real-life applications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See [Uniformization of Riemann Surfaces](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/chan/fulldraft7.pdf) by Kevin Timothy Chan and (paywalled) [The Uniformization Theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320507?seq=1) by William Abikoff.

Comment: Just beware of the fact that the 3rd proof given in Kevin Chan's notes is very incomplete. It is a classical continuity argument going back to Poincare (who after much effort abandoned the approach). It can be justified once you know that the moduli space is connected and if you know few other modern tools.